# Gradle up-to-date check and doLast

Tags: gradle

```
task myJar(type: Jar) {

   doLast {

        // process jar, e.g. proguard jar, override the same jar
        tasks.proguardJar.execute()
   }

}
```

Gradle creates hash for task inputs and outputs for UP_TO_DATE check. When will they be created?  before doFirst and after doLast?

Answer (score 0):

Before doFirst and after doLast sounds right.

Recent gradle versions are stricter when it comes to changes in the file containing doFirst and doLast blocks, though. Any textual change will now cause the task to be out-of-date.